# Корректно ли такое употребление кавычек?

Tags: пунктуация

К сожалению, сегодня фирмы-«скороспелки» нередко не имеют и половины необходимого штата специалистов; при этом найденные на скорую руку проектировщики-«кочевники», разменявшие не один десяток рабочих мест, не всегда оправдывают ожидания.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что кавычки здесь не нужны. Слово "скороспелка" со сходным значением есть в словаре, значение слова "кочевники" также понятно.

СКОРОСПЕЛКА, - Разг. 1. ж. Скороспелый плод; растение, приносящее такие плоды. Дыня-скороспелка. Картошка-скороспелка. Груша-скороспелка. 2. м. и ж. Человек, слишком рано развившийся, слишком рано и обычно без надлежащей подготовки выступивший на каком-л. поприще. Писатель-скороспелка. Командир-скороспелка.

Например (из Интернета): Компании-скороспелки с помощью агрессивной рекламы завлекают доверчивых клиентов.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ли вообще заключать в кавычки часть слова, написанного через дефис?

Comment: Мне такие написания не встречались.

Answer (score -1):

> Спасибо. А можно ли вообще заключать в кавычки часть слова,
>   написанного через дефис?

Такую практику трудно назвать правильной. Вообще я не видел зафиксированных рекомендаций по этому поводу, но тут такая вещь, что записанное через дефис понимается орфографически  как одно слово. Кому-то придет в голову заключать в кавычки *часть слова*?

Что касается необходимости заключения в кавычки слова "скороспелка" или "кочевники" безотносительно к наличию дефиса, то не могу сказать, что они  такое уж очевидное, что понятно без кавычек. Сильно от контекста зависит, от стиля, целевой аудитории и т. п. В вашем случае я бы, пожалуй, закавычил, а с учетом дефисного написания сделал бы для целиком с первой частью:

*К сожалению, сегодня «фирмы-скороспелки» нередко не имеют и половины необходимого штата специалистов; при этом найденные на скорую руку «проектировщики-кочевники», разменявшие не один десяток рабочих мест, не всегда оправдывают ожидания.*

Спорный, конечно, подход, но результат выглядит вполне нормально. Другое дело, что тут многовато будет двух таких случаев на одну фразу. Если пестрит в глазах, то оставьте без кавычек оба случая, тоже в общем-то ошибкой не будет.

//----

Я вот подумал. Если так необходимо забрать в кавычки именно одно слово, то, видимо, надо будет просто опустить дефис. Правило тоже нигде не описано, но некая аналогия есть в том, что дефис заменяется на пробел, если приложение, идущее после главного слова, - имя собственное.

Comment: Результат выглядит неважно, и  глазах пестрит. Приведите примеры подобных написаний в каких-либо источниках.

Comment: Результат выглядит прекрасно. А источники... Можно я Вам Вашими же словами отвечу? Вы хоть книжку бы какую почитали, прежде чем спрашивать.